# Singular value decomposition in two spaces (reference in Russian paper?)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $X$ be a Banach space such that $H \cap X$ is dense in both. 
Now, let $T$ be an operator such that $T: H \rightarrow H$ and $T:X \rightarrow X$ exists in the sense that both definitions of $T$ coincide on the dense set. 
Moreover, I assume that $T$ is in both cases a compact operator. 
Then, functional analysis books tell me that $T$ admits a singular value decomposition on $H$:
$$T(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}  \lambda_i \langle v_i,x \rangle w_i$$
with $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle = \langle w_i,w_j \rangle  =\delta_{ij}.$

Is it true that $v_i$ and $w_j$ can be chosen from $H\cap X$?

**Update:** I found compelling evidence that the answer to this problem may be contained in the following paper:

**I. C. GOHBERG AND M. K. ZAMBICKII, Normally solvable operators in spaces with two norms, Bul.
Akad. Sci. RSS Moldoven, 6 (1964), pp. 80-84. (In Russian.)**

Unfortunately, I could not find the paper nor am I able to translate the title into Russian to look for it. But if anybody is able to exhibit this paper and could provide a brief explanation whether it indeed answers the equation, I would be most greatful.

Best,

Kermit

Comment: The Russian citation is "И.Ц. Гохберг, М.К. Замбицкий; О нормально разрешимых операторах в пространствах с двумя нормами, Изв. АН Молд. ССР, 1964". But I doubt that will help you very much, since the article doesn't seem to be online.